# Can we have sha256 secret key support in Loadrunner, if so how?

Tags: loadrunner

**Can we have sha256 secret key support in Loadrunner, if so how??**
I am using LR 9.52.
I have a script for SHA256 **but not** with secret key. I am expecting something similar to what we have in Perl "use Digest::SHA qw(hmac_sha256_base64);
my $digest = hmac_sha256_base64 ($request, $self->{SecretKey});"

Answer (score 0):

I've written a SHA-1 for LoadRunner.

You can find it at  http://ptfrontline.wordpress.com/2010/03/02/sha-1-hash-for-loadrunner/